UISwitch addTarget fails to call an allocated function from a different class
While coding in Objective-C, I stumbled upon something very weird. When I add an allocated target to a UISwitch from a different class, it doesn't get called. But if the function is deallocated it gets called normally.
Can someone explain this to me and is there anyway to call an allocated function from a different class in a UISwitch?
Doesn't work:
@implementation CustomClass : NSObject
-(void) test {
    
    NSLog(@"TEST");
}
@end

UISwitch *uiSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 50)];
[uiSwitch addTarget:[CustomClass alloc] action:@selector(test) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self addSubview:uiSwitch];

Works:
@implementation CustomClass : NSObject
+(void) test {
    
    NSLog(@"TEST");
}
@end


UISwitch *uiSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 50)];
[uiSwitch addTarget:[CustomClass class] action:@selector(test) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self addSubview:uiSwitch];


You have two issues with your non-working code:

You are not calling an appropriate init method on CustomClass. You need at least something like:
[[CustomClass alloc] init]


addTarget does not retain the object you pass to the target parameter. This is stated in the documentation:

The control does not retain the object in the target parameter. It is your responsibility to maintain a strong reference to the target object while it is attached to a control.



So you need to store the CustomClass instance in an instance variable of the class that is creating the UISwitch in addition to initializing the instance correctly.

Your working code works because no instance of CustomClass needs to be created to call the static test method.

FYI - You wrote:

But if the function is deallocated it gets called normally.

What you mean is:

But if the function is static, it gets called normally.


@HangerRash. thanks for the edit and taking your time to answer this but sadly it still doesnt get called :/
[uiSwitch addTarget:[[CustomClass alloc] init] action:@selector(test) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

That only follows half of my answer. You also need to store the instance in an instance variable.
